# IN condition in Where clause on Peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, orm, peewee

I would like to accomplish something like an SQL 'IN' condition for the where clause in Python's Peewee ORM.

```
Order.select().where(Order.statusid in statuses)
```

Is this possible?

I am using Postgres in case there is any compatibility issues with any proposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html) found out that there a specific query operations for IN lookup: *.in_(value)*

So I guess this is how it would actually work:

```
Order.select().where(Order.statusid.in_(statuses))
```

Comment: Yes, once has to look carefully for that in the API! thanks @Filip

Answer (score 3):

This works too:

```
Order.select().where(Order.statusid << statuses)
```

More elegant than the actual .in_ method :)

Comment: This means you're already paying attention to the API documentation, the operators are equivalent, you are correct :)

Comment: Would be awesome if the syntax `.where(attr in list)`  could be supported, i may open a discussion on peewee's Github later this week

Comment: Python doesn't allow it, Python coerces the return value of `__contains__` to a boolean.